# Payment method are not shown in admin magento 2

Tags: magento2

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="payment">
                <group id="worldpaydirect" translate="label" sortOrder="2" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Custom Payment</label>
                    <field id="active" translate="label comment" sortOrder="1" type="select" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                        <label>Enable</label>
                        <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                    </field>
                </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Admin:
https://prnt.sc/mgtna4

In above screenshot custom Payment is not appear  in **stores>configuration>sales>payment methods**

Comment: check with clear cache

Comment: i was tried it already nothing happens

Comment: @divyasekar Please check your 'var/log/system.xml' and 'exception.log' file and there is any error or warning log related to this

Comment: @divyasekar you can try my code

Comment: There is no any recent log @saneer Ladani

Comment: your code is in this - 'app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/system.xml' path right ?.

Comment: i have checked your code in my local system and it is perfect. this is not code related issue. i think some small mistak with your module and file

Comment: module file means @saneer Ladani

Comment: Means remove space OR file path is right etc. LIKE  from '  <space>  <?xml version="1.0"?>'  TO '<?xml version="1.0"?>'  check system.xml file

Comment: thank you its was a space problem @Saneer Ladani

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please remove space before the **xml** TAG. check below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
        <system>
            <section id="payment">
                    <group id="worldpaydirect" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="34" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                        <label>Custom Payment</label>
                        <field id="active" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0" canRestore="1">
                            <label>Enabled</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                        </field>
                    </group>
            </section>
        </system>
    </config>
```

Then run this command

php bin/magento cache:flush